# SvelteKit - api response data (PageData) not updated after initial render

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

am new to svelte and svelteKit in general and am trying to load data from api and I followed the sveltekit todo sample code. It's working well for initial rendering and `a` tag onClick but in div `on:click` am updating url parameters api getting called and returns data but `PageData` object not updating.

Here I have attached my `onClick`

```
import { goto } from '$app/navigation'; 
const adhigaramClick = (adhigaram: string) => {
        selectedAdhigaram = adhigaram
        $page.url.searchParams.set('adhigaram',adhigaram); 
        goto(`?${$page.url.searchParams.toString()}`);
    }
```

Here I have attached the api call (`+page.server.ts`)

```
    export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({url, params}) => {
    let selectedPaal = "test;

    const paramPaal =url.searchParams.get("paal")
    const adhigaram =url.searchParams.get("adhigaram")

        if (paramPaal) {
            selectedPaal = paramPaal;
        }
        
    const response = await api('GET', `page/${selectedPaal}${adhigaram?`/${adhigaram}` : ''}`);
    
    if (response.status === 404) {
        return {
            data: {}  as Page
        };
    }

    if (response.status === 200) {  
        return {
            ... (await response.json()) as Data
        };
    }
    throw error(response.status);
};
```

`+page.svelte.ts` file to get the response data(`PageData`)

```
import type { PageData } from './$types';

    export let data: PageData;
    $: console.log(data);
```

`a` tag click is working fine page re rendering

```
<a href={`?paal=${paal.keyword}`} >
    {paal.titleTamil}
</a>
```

Comment: There is no place in your code where you call "adhigaramClick".
Do you have a minimal +page.ts and +page.server.ts file that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: I have a list of div am calling that "adhigaramClick" function while user clicks on the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalidation is probably what you need.

> SvelteKit tracks the dependencies of each `load` function to avoid
> re-running it unnecessarily during navigation. For example, a `load`
> function in a root `+layout.js` doesn't need to re-run when you
> navigate from one page to another unless it references `url` or a
> member of `params` that changed since the last navigation.
>
> A `load` function will re-run in the following situations:
>
> - It references a property of `params` whose value has changed
> - It references a property of `url` (such as `url.pathname` or `url.search`) whose value has changed
> - It calls `await parent()` and a parent `load` function re-ran
> - It declared a dependency on a specific URL via `fetch` or `depends`, and that URL was marked invalid with `invalidate(url)`
> - All active load functions were forcibly re-run with `invalidate()`
>
> If a `load` function is triggered to re-run, the page will not remount — instead, it will update with the new `data`. This means that components' internal state is preserved. If this isn't want you want, you can reset whatever you need to reset inside an `afterNavigate` callback, and/or wrap your component in a `{#key ...}` block.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#invalidation

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @FlippingBinary's answer, my issue was not that the load function was not rerunning, but that the UI was not updating.

The `{#key ...}` block fixed the rerendering for me.

https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key

J

Answer (score 0):

To those encountering data update issues with slot content within components, consider this solution:

```
<script>
...
$: data, data = data
...
</script>
```

This technique triggers re-rendering upon data changes, ensuring component awareness of updates. No need to use a heavy call such as `invalidateAll()`